# Confusion related to the DAVID tool

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-expression

I am trying to use the DAVID tool to do some gene analysis. I have some probe set intensities for some cancer cell lines. I found this link in the DAVID tool http://david.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/tools.jsp. I am a bit confused with the terminology introduced here. It says gene list for the probe sets why is it so? I mean in the example you can see the probe sets like

1007_s_at
1053_at
117_at
121_at
1255_g_at
1294_at
1316_at
1320_at
1405_i_at
1431_at
1438_at
1487_at
1494_f_at
1598_g_at

Buy why are they called gene list not probe sets. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit confusing, but DAVID uses the term Gene List as a generic term.

Looking at Step 2, you can submit many kinds of lists to DAVID, including actual gene symbols, Ensembl or RefSeq Accessions, etc... actually nearly 30 kinds of terms including 'not sure' which probably looks at your list and tries to guess.

Affymetrix or Illumina probe set IDs are each designed to measure a gene, ideally, though its not precisely a one Probe Set to one Gene relationship.  This is because when the array is designed there may be a partial transcript RNA records which turn out later to be parts of a single gene.  There are also probe sets which may turn out to hybridize to similar sequences in more than one gene.

Its messy, but its also true that often more than one gene symbol will appear for the same gene because of historical naming conventions...